# TEI P5 XSLT add span class in generated html

Tags: xml, xslt

In my XML TEI P5 have some arabic and hebrew text sections that I like to transform via XSLT to html.

I'm thinking to mark the arabic/hebrew texts with a  tag and format it within css to `text-align: right;`

For example I have an arabic/hebrew string "foobar" in

excerpt from xml:

```
<title>Ordre de la 
  <hi rend="italic">Haggadah de Pessaḥ</hi>
  <right-to-left>foobar ות והמופתים שעשה הקב''ה לאבותינו)</right-to-left>
</title>
```

excerpt from xslt:

```
<xsl:if test="tei:right-to-left">
  <span class="right-to-left">
    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value"/>
  </span>
</xsl:if>
```

My Goal is to merge the text (e.g. beginning with foobar) within `<right-to-left>` tag in new html-tag `<span class="right-to-left">`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could adapt an existing rule to achieve this with:

```
<xsl:if test="starts-with($value, 'right-to-left') "><xsl:text>right-to-left </xsl:text></xsl:if>
```